# Connection fails to Salesforce Marketing Cloud from Azure Linked Services

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create a Linked Service to Salesforce Marketing Cloud in Azure. Purpose of this is to integrate Salesforce Marketing Cloud with Azure Data Factory.

In Salesforce Marketing Cloud I have:

1. Created a new Package inside of Platform Tools -> Apps -> Installed Packages
2. Created an Api Integration component instead of the newly created package

I've got the client id and client secret from the newly created component and I've added them into the Azure Marketing Cloud linked service configuration like here:

[image: salesforce marketing cloud linked service configuration]

When I test the connection, I get the following error:

```
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][SalesforceMarketingCloud] (62) API Connection Failed. Forbidden Request. HTTP Response code: 401 ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][SalesforceMarketingCloud] (62) API Connection Failed. Forbidden Request. HTTP Response code: 401
```

There are additional settings in Salesforce like: Authentication Base URI, REST Base URI or SOAP Base URI  and there is no option to add them on Azure's end. This probably indicates that this is not the correct approach, but this is as far as I got.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Thank you

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce-marketing-cloud),The Salesforce Marketing Cloud connector supports OAuth 2 authentication. It is built on top of the Salesforce Marketing Cloud REST API.So I think you can try to configure REST.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I followed the article. When you create an API integration component in Salesforce, you'll get: client, secret and urls. Azure Salesforce Marketing Cloud connector has option to add client and secret, but no URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Linked Service from Azure Data Factory is referencing a legacy type of Salesforce package which doesn't exist anymore in Salesforce.

Microsoft needs to update the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Linked Service. Here are some mentions about this:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/45574

Same page provides a workaround with a different kind of linked service (ODBC)
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/45574#issuecomment-571271107